# Bootstrap dropdown - Click event triggers only on the first click

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a bunch of dropdown menus, and I have a click listener attached to document. When I click the dropdown anchor the click event is not triggering.

After some digging in, its because bootstrap is preventing propagation. It is demonstrated in the below JSbin

`$(document).on('click', function(e){
  console.log('Click triggered');
});`

http://jsbin.com/lununufaqa/edit?html,js,console,output

Anyway to overcome this?

Answer (score -1):

Replace your menu.component.html with below and this will start working.

```
<div class="dropdown" *ngFor='let menu of menuItem; let i = index'>
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" *ngIf="menu" [attr.data-target]="'#navbarmobile'+ i" (click)="do()">{{menu.name}}</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Get more info from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Sorry that was not what I was asking for,  the click is working only once. The subsequent clicks on the button are not triggering click event.

Comment: Click event not working because you get error in console. And if you see the closely it's triggered from dropdown.js. Inorder to fix this you have to change in your template.

Comment: Could you tell me what error you are getting in console? I have attached a "click" listener on the "document", which should trigger when I click the button regardless. The click triggers for the first click of the button, but on the second it doesn't.